# How to let stats.multivariate_normal.rvs return an array instead of scalar?

Tags: numpy, scipy, statistics, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

How to let `stats.multivariate_normal.rvs` return an array instead of scalar?

I wan to keep the code structure of slicing [k] position of the returned value, so it would be great if it returns an one by one array instead of a scalar when my `stats.multivariate_normal.rvs` is in fact univariate normal.

`np.array(result)[0]` doesn't work. Any suggestions?

`np.array(result, ndmin=1)[0]` works. Any better suggestions?

Comment: I *think* I understand the problem, and I *think* it might be a bug in the `rvs` method, but it would be helpful if you added to the question a small, reproducible example (i.e. something that anyone can copy and run) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: See, for example, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7689